# How to get product's comparable attributes list by product id

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, products, custom-attributes, compare

I would like to know, the process to get list of comparable attributes of a product with their label/name and their values.

i'm using this, but it's not working.

```
$attributes = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Compare\Item\Collection');
            $attributes->getComparableAttributes();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
            $collection->create();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) 
            {
                $collection->addAttributeToSelect($attribute->getAttributeCode());
            }
           $collection->load();
            $collection->setPageSize(1);
```

can anyone know. thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-comparable-attribute-list-programmatically-in-magento-2/ check using link

Answer (score 0):

You have to set visitor Id for collection first and then get comparable attributes

like this

```
$attributes = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Compare\Item\Collection')->setVisitorId($visitorId);
$attributes->getComparableAttributes();
```